# Removing own answer posted few seconds after someone else's and is essentially the same

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

Consider the following situation - I and some other guy posted an answer, and the other guy's answer was let's say five seconds faster than mine. After comparing them, it seems that the answers are very similar and doesn't have any significant difference and the nature of question **doesn't let me add something that increase answer value**. In that case I think I need to remove mine because

- My answer doesn't add anything valueable;
- I wasn't first;

Am I right with that way to go?

Comment: Sometimes it is just nice to see the same thing expressed in different words. Some wordings may be easier to understand for some than others.

Comment: My advice: stop wasting your time answering quick, easy questions `:P`

Comment: You really put too much weight into being first. Let the votes decide whose is better.

Comment: 5 seconds difference is practically negligible - you clearly couldn't have known that the other answer would be posted at the same time. If it were 10 minutes, then yeah, you probably shouldn't bother answering in the first place. Also, you can always add more information to your answer to make it better than other existing ones...

Comment: @Dukeling from personal experience losing an answer snipe race (for a simple question) by enough to show a 1 minute difference between when your answer was posted and when the first was posted (or if the 1st answer already got at least 1 up vote) is enough that the other person will always get significantly more votes; even if the second answer posted is edited up to be significantly better than the one that won the snipe race.

Comment: @DanNeely In a simple question (not that I really answer those any more), sure, that's mostly true, although giving it a few minutes, or simply leaving your answer there because it's more useful (even slightly ... to some) doesn't really hurt.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the other answer to be wrong.  That would be a bad choice and I would never do that.

Comment: @Hogan O_O what makes you think I'm considering something like that?

Comment: @AlexeyMalev - I don't, it was a joke.

Comment: @Cupcake Yeah but notice how answers to the question "is java pass by reference or value" get 1000+ upvotes whereas complex answers get maybe 3-10 upvotes if you're lucky. This community encourages answering easy questions: that's how the reputation system is designed.

Comment: @KyleM are you referring to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/456814)? That question is 5 years old and would not pass current guidelines for good questions. Ask something like that nowadays and it'll be closed and downvoted to oblivion. Besides, it's a community wiki now, and thus doesn't even generate any rep anymore.

Comment: @Cupcake I'm using an example to make a point. The point is what's important, not the example. This community encourages answering simple questions because answers to simple questions get more attention and upvotes. That's my opinion, not a fact, but I think many people here will agree. If a highly technical, very difficult, or niche question is asked that is difficult to answer, the answer will not be understood by many people and thus will not earn upvotes. By the way, I love the community I'm not saying I don't. :)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

> Am I right with that way to go?

## Yes

Feel free to remove your answer if it's not going to add anything more, and you feel that the other answer is objectively better. A great thing about this community is how supportive it can be.

## No

Feel free to elaborate on your answer to make sure that it's comprehensive and is a *better* answer than the competition. If you've got more detail than the other answer, or even can add more detail it's better to invest a bit more time into answering, even if you weren't quite the fastest gun in the west.

## Maybe

I've done both, and it really comes down to a judgement call. When I'm in a competitive mood or feel like I can eke out some additional reputation points, I'll beef up my answer in hopes of earning more magical unicorn points. When I feel like it's not worth elaborating on my own answer, I'll often remove it and add a comment on the better answer to address any areas that could use improvement.

In the end it's about making Stack Overflow *the very best* resource on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, my vision seems to be the same.

Comment: I will usually leave my answer but if the other answer is better, I'll either comment on it or on my own answer that the other is better.  I think it's useful just to have different words, or fill out various corners that were left uncovered from the other answer.  Even easy answers usually have small variations that expose extra education about the language being used.  Only occasionally is an answer so black and white that there's only one way to answer it, and they usually are good and answered by the time I see them anyway.

Comment: Minor typo fix ("[eke](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eke)" not "[eek](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eek)"); unless you were citing this [meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83625), in which case I can only apologise... ;)

Comment: @DavidThomas, eke! oh wait that's eek! good catch.

Comment: @zzzzBov, I love your going with all three possibilities.  It's a perfect answer.

Comment: How can you make a better answer if the OP has already accepted the answer they liked best?

Comment: @GayotFow, picking an answer doesn't stop anyone from adding an answer, nor does it prevent anyone from editing existing answers. Quality is usually measured by upvotes, and often the OP will select the best answer, but it's also quite common for another answer to outvote the accepted answer. [There's even a badge for outscoring the accepted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/39/populist).

Answer (score 11):

If, and only if, you feel that your answer doesn't add anything valuable, then go ahead and remove it.  Alternatively, if there is some extra bit of clarification you could add to your answer instead of a "this is what you're doing wrong", then that would make your answer more useful to the community at large.

I wouldn't remove an answer because I wasn't first; I've often taken those opportunities to add more information to my answer, and provide a bit more explanation as to *why* that answer is viable.

Comment: Your statement makes sense, but in one particular case made me to ask this question, I wasn't really able to add something valueable to my answer and thus decided to remove it as there was one added before mine.

Comment: I'd say then what you did was justified, if you truly believe that you couldn't add anything more to what the other answer had provided.

Answer (score 8):

## Yes

If your answer doesn't add any value to Stack Overflow, then you should delete it.

This is a special case of the more general rule: If *any* answer doesn't add any value to Stack Overflow, it should be deleted.

This is a special case of the more general rule: If any question **or** answer (**or even** comment) doesn't add any value to Stack Overflow, it should be deleted.

The salient difference in this case is that **you have the power to take action** (whereas in general it's really hard to get an arbitrary question or answer deleted).

Sure, you could leave your identical answer and just hope that the other guy comes back to delete his, but that's extremely unlikely to happen. It's much more helpful for you to delete *your* answer (the one you have the power to delete).

---

## Don't forget

that you can even **edit** the other guy's answer to make it more helpful or more complete. For example, if his answer is identical to yours except that he opens it with "OP is an idiot", you can edit away that part of his answer. Or, if it's correct except that it should really have a footnote about how the situation is subtly different in K&R Objective-C++17, you can add that footnote. Minor edits should be made **as** edits; otherwise, the list of answers starts to look like a Wikipedia revision history, with each minor correction posted as a new answer.

If the grass needs mowing, mow it — don't [wait for the other guy to mow *his* part](https://www.sciencemag.org/content/162/3859/1243.full).

Comment: "K&R Objective-C++17" :) Just imagining something like this is sure to give one nightmares. Ssssh. Don't wake the sleeping monsters. The clang codebase is way too easy to modify and someone could unleash such a monster 11 months from now.

Comment: +1 for the "Don't forget". One pretty common case I run into is that my answer does add value, but only because I linked to the docs and the other guy didn't, or I formatted my quote from the docs and he didn't. In a case like that, it's completely harmless and clearly beneficial to edit the link or formatting into the other guy's answer, after which my own answer can be deleted with no loss.