# Adding answers after a correct answer already exists?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

I see this happen all of the time. Somebody answers a question, correctly I might add, and even after a few minutes, there are more/other people posting extremely similar answers that do the same thing.

Why are people copying/duplicating answers? My first impression is that they want to get an answer in as many questions on the off-chance that they get reputation from it, even if it adds no new content to the thread.

Am I wrong in my assumption? Is there good reason to dilute a question with as many same-answers as possible? Should I downvote the duplicated answers based on their time-stamp?

Comment: Related: [The Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: Most people, once they start writing an answer, will finish it and post it regardless of whether or not another answer is posted while they are writing theirs.

Comment: The kinds of answers I'm talking about, though are similar to the related link by @hichris123. They are all very short, not well explained, and not extremely helpful. You can tell by the difference in the time-stamps, that these people saw there was an already correct answer, and still decided to post their duplicate solution anyways.

Comment: @NickDugger Your question says you're talking about posts within a few minutes of each other.  When you see answers that close it's quite reasonable to assume that the post author didn't see other answers when posting theirs, or at least was in the process of writing their answer when it was posted.  Keep in mind it's the time from when the page was loaded, not the time they started actually typing in the answer box.  If the answer was posted while reading the question, the user may not have noticed it.

Comment: Maybe related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256171/what-to-do-if-theres-a-better-answer-than-mine/256189#256189

Comment: @Servy Still though when I see that somebody else answered the same thing *before* me, I generally delete my answer as redundant. No point in duplicating the same answers.

Comment: @user000001 And you're in the minority there.

Comment: I dunno, I do the same, which is why I brought it up.

Comment: Generally people have patterns of behavior - someone who is posting duplicate answers for reputation is going to post them on lots of questions, while someone who is answering to be helpful is going to have answers on questions no one else touched or adequately covered, too (or still have few answers overall).

Comment: @NickDugger Keep doing that, that's the right way. Posting duplicate answers is simply repwhoring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because:

The bad reasons:

- People care more about reputation than the quality of the site.
- People care more about being rewarded for their efforts than the quality of the site.

The good reason:

- People feel that their answer adds something beyond the other answer(s).

> Is there good reason to dilute a question with [a very similar answer]?

It may be a slightly different phrasing or take on the problem, which some may find more helpful than the first answer.

Don't assume it won't be helpful to anyone just because the two look similar to you - the first could, for example, use bigger words and more complex sentences and thus be a lot more difficult for non-native English speakers to understand, while you barely notice the difference yourself.

If no-one would find the second answer more helpful than the first, then no, there isn't a good reason to do this.

> Should I downvote the duplicated answers based on their time-stamp?

Personally, I'd only consider downvoting if: (and yes, all of the below are fairly subjective)

- It's sufficiently likely that the new answerer only **started** writing their answer **after** the first answer was posted, and
- It's sufficiently similar to the other answer that I feel it's just an attempt to score some reputation.

And, I might consider: (although I rarely downvote for this reason, perhaps incorrectly so)

- The other answer is better and I don't feel it adds **any** value beyond the other answer.

But you get to pick your own criteria for voting.