# Late answer is worse than others

Tags: discussion, flags

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426397/string-manipulation-in-python) old question just got a new answer that, albeit correct (it does give the desired result), it is by all criteria, worse than the ones already posted in many ways. I think this ought to be eventually deleted, as it adds nothing useful to the site; but should it be flagged? Or should it be dealt with by downvoting?

In the benefit of posterity, in case it gets deleted, the answer suggest using:

```
x[:len(x)-3:+1]
```

when the "correct" (simple, efficient, legible) way is:

```
x[:-3]
```

Related questions:

- [How to respond to late answers that are duplicates of accepted answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250883/how-to-respond-to-late-answers-that-are-duplicates-of-accepted-answers)
- [Adding answers after a correct answer already exists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258344/adding-answers-after-a-correct-answer-already-exists)

I don't believe they are duplicates because in this case, the answer is of lower quality and doesn't provide a real alternative or an explanation.

Comment: Related though probably non-duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255572

Comment: @Deduplicator that is indeed very relevant. I understand that this should be flagged too.

Answer (score 14):

No, wrong or unhelpful answers should be *downvoted*, not deleted or flagged.

I might also leave a comment along the lines *your answer doesn't add anything new that wasn't already said in other answers, and better*.

Comment: In the post linked by [Deduplicator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255571/what-to-do-with-late-answers-which-retread-the-same-ground-as-previous-answers/255572#255572), the mods recommend custom flagging for a similar case. The problem is not wrongfulness, it is lack of added value.

Comment: @Davidmh: hrmz, not sure I agree that *moderator intervention* is always needed in such cases. I'd just leave a comment and leave it to voting to do the rest.