# Multiple answer with essentially same content - is it accepted to downvote?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting, accepted-answer

Is it accepted to downvote people who post the same answer that has been posted before by somebody else for the same question? I mean I see a lot of question that has 3 answers with essentially same content. Shouldn't the first answer be upvoted, and the remaining 2 downvoted for posting the same thing?

Comment: When it is copy pasted, flag as plagiarism. If it just has the same content, look at each answer in isolation and see if its good. Also note that often people take some time to type their answer, so if there isn't a lot of time in between two, they may be independent. Questions with objectively correct answers often look alike.

Comment: I'm not talking about copy paste, I'm saying if there are two answers saying the same thing without any extra information, but differently phrased, is it OK to downvote the one that got posted some minutes later? And upvote the first answer.

Comment: no, why? just because someone was quicker a few minuntes writing that answer? what would you think if you wrote an answer, put some effort into it, and after finishing and posting it, you discover someone was three minutes earlier? would you think that your answer is not useful (as the downvote button text says)?

Comment: Yes, I would try to add some extra information, or if I can't, I delete my own answer if somebody was faster than me.

Comment: That sounds like a silly thing to do. Your answer might be easier understood by some people than the other one.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind next time then :). I found a possible duplicate for my own question, hehe. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252451/removing-own-answer-posted-few-seconds-after-someone-elses-and-is-essentially-t

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it accepted to downvote people who post the same answer that has been posted before by somebody else for the same question?

Yes. For the simple reason that you can use your vote as you see fit. The real question though is whether or not you should vote accordingly.

Let's assume we're not dealing with plagiarism here.

Sometimes a question has an obvious answer. And it near simultaneously gets several answers, all of which essentially state the same. Do we need all of those answers? Not really, but they don't do harm either. Perhaps they are somewhat differently phrased, and their train of thought connects better with that of some users than the other answers. In such a case I see no reason to downvote.

If there is an old question however, and an answer comes in plainly repeating what already has been said, one could argue the contribution isn't all that useful. If I can personally clearly establish that for myself, I might downvote it for not being useful. But it's not something I regularly do.

Comment: When a new answer is posted to an old question, and that new answer simply repeats other earlier answers, I usually post a comment asking the poster to explain how their answer provides additional, relevant information that wasn't previously stated. Frequently, they delete the answer; if they don't, I usually add a custom flag explaining the situation, and a mod typically does so.